# Pytthon.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

i have problem , when i try to run file .py with matplotlib ,suddenly show alert python.exe has stopped working

and, this is my code :

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = scipy.io.loadmat('ex3data1.mat')

image = data ['X'][5]

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(np.asmatrix(image).reshape(20,20).transpose(), cmap = 'Greys')
plt.show()
```

anyone can solve that ?

Comment: What's the error message if you run it from a shell?

Comment: @ChristianJonassen yes , i run from command windows 7 , just show alert python.exe has stopped working

Comment: General debugging technique: do a "print" after each line, see how far your program gets.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen when i print its work , but when i use matplotlib to show data with 3d ,suddenly show alert python.exe has stopped working

Comment: I would try to do asmatrix, reshape and transpose before the imshow and print the size of the item. A 20x20 matrix you even can even print all value to check there is othing invalid.

Comment: @Vince can you give me example , how to do this ?

Comment: image = data ['X'][5]\
print type(image),image.shape\
A = np.asmatrix(image)\
print type(A),A.shape\
A.reshape(20,20)\
print type(A),A.shape\
A.transpose()\
print type(A),A.shape\